# Discord.js sending a message in 1 minute intervals

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Hello I'm trying to send out an automated message to discord but I keep getting the following error:

```
bot.sendMessage is not a function
```

I'm unsure as to why I'm getting this error, below is my code;

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var bot = new Discord.Client()

bot.on('ready', function() {
    console.log(bot.user.username);
});

bot.on('message', function() {
    if (message.content === "$loop") { 
      var interval = setInterval (function () {
        bot.sendMessage(message.channel, "123")
      }, 1 * 1000); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Lennart is correct, you can't use `bot.sendMessage` because `bot` is a `Client` class, and doesn't have the `sendMessage` function. That's the tip of the iceberg. What you're looking for is [`send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) (or the old version, [`sendMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=sendMessage)).

These functions can't be used directly from the `Client` Class (which is what `bot` is, they are used on a [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel) class. So how do you get this `TextChannel`? You get it **from** the [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) class. In your sample code, you aren't actually getting a `Message` object from your `bot.on('message'...` listener, but you should!

The callback function to `bot.on('...` should look something like this:

```
// add message as a parameter to your callback function
bot.on('message', function(message) {
    // Now, you can use the message variable inside
    if (message.content === "$loop") { 
        var interval = setInterval (function () {
            // use the message's channel (TextChannel) to send a new message
            message.channel.send("123")
            .catch(console.error); // add error handling here
        }, 1 * 1000); 
    }
});
```

You'll also notice I added `.catch(console.error);` after using `message.channel.send("123")` because Discord expects their `Promise`-returning functions to handle errors.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is returning the error, because `Discord.Client()` doesn't have a method called `sendMessage()` as can be seen in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client).

If you would like to send a message, you should do it in the following way;

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var bot = new Discord.Client()

bot.on('ready', function() {
    console.log(bot.user.username);
});

bot.on('message', function() {
    if (message.content === "$loop") { 
      var interval = setInterval (function () {
        message.channel.send("123")
      }, 1 * 1000); 
    }
});
```

I recommend familiarising yourself with the documentation for discord.js which can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).